# History.js howto questions and behaviour in IE9 and FF3

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-history, history.js

I would like to use [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) but it doesn't work as expected and I'm not sure if I do it the right way...

Here is what I did:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery ScrollTo Plugin -->
<script defer src="mySite/js/jquery.scrollto.min.js"></script>

<!-- JSON2 Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript">if ( typeof window.JSON === 'undefined' ) { document.write('<script src="mySite/js/json2.js"><\/script>'); }</script>

<!-- jQuery ScrollTo Plugin -->
<script src="mySite/js/amplify.store.min.js"></script>

<!-- History.js --> 
<script defer src="mySite/js/history.adapter.jquery.js"></script> 
<script defer src="mySite/js/history.js"></script>
<script defer src="mySite/js/history.html4.js"></script>

<!-- ajaxify-mySite.js --> 
<script defer src="mySite/js/ajaxify-mySite.js"></script>
```

The ajaxify-mySite.js script is mostly the same as it is shown [here](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify)

Thats whats going wrong:

In IE9 I get urls like "http://www.mySite.com/index.php/tools.html#index.php/contact.html?&_suid=478" (it should be "http://www.mySite.com/index.php#contact.html?&_suid=478" I think) and the content won't load the most time..

My FF3.6.21 loads all pages without using this script - is this normal behaviour?

Thanks!